# How to enable shadows on glossy surface with enviromental mapping?

Tags: shadows

[image]So I am a noob in blender.. but scene is in attachment.

As you can see, I dont get any hard shadows. With Sun size 0.062. How can I re-enable hard shadows so they are visible or what shader can I use to enable them again?

On diffuse they work fine, I removed diffuse because I wasn't sure if it was needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use another type of light source, like *Area* lights, preferably. Also, notice that you've got an old version of Blender. Maybe the *Principled BSDF* shader in Blender 2.8 could give you more flexibility.